# "вата" meaning something other than "wool"?

Tags: словоупотребление

> - И еще один вопрос интересующий больше русских верующих —  правда ли, что  в День Света на плите Гроба  лежит вата?
> - Нет. В  день Света на плите Святого Гроба  нет ваты. Там стоят лампады.

Source: http://armenianchurch.do.am/publ/paskhalnoe_palomnichestvo_v_ierusalim/2-1-0-44

Google translates this as

> - Another issue of interest to many Russian believers - is it true that on the Day of Light at the plate Holy Sepulchre is wool?
> - No. On the day of the World at the plate Holy Sepulchre is not wool. There are lamps.

A more accurate translation would be appreciated, but I am especially bewildered by the translation of "вата" or "ваты" as "wool", which makes no sense, when something quite different (perhaps "miraculous"?) would be expected. Every online dictionary I can find fails to provide any meaning of "вата" or "ваты" as anything but "wool" or the like. Is this some sort of idiom?

Comment: It is important to state that вата means cotton wool only while other kinds of wool are reffered by different names.

Comment: There is also `сахарная вата` (cotton candy, lit. "sugar wool").

Comment: I recommend you to google your word if you want know exactly meaning. In your case it is useful - https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=XppbVaaqCcyjsAGP5IDgDQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=1017

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a religious person, but from the source it seems there were debates on how the candles on the slab are lit. People ask if they are lit from cotton wool. A quick google search shows that there might be implications that the cotton wool (if placed on the slab) can be lit by some miraculous act:

> После солнца - тотчас облако, потом роса и вследствие росы - Огонь. Роса падает на вату, которая лежит на Гробе Господнем, - и мокрая вата вдруг загорается голубым Огнём

But the father answers that there is no wool on the slab, just oil lamps.

So yes, the question is about cotton wool:

> And another question that interests mainly Russian believers: is it true that on the Day of Light [not sure how it is called in English, it is the Saturday of the Holy Week] there is cotton wool on the slab of the Holy Sepulcher?
>
> No, there is no wool on the slab of the Holy Sepulcher on the Day of Light. There are only oil lamps.